# Windows service crashes with WebClient.DownloadData(url) on external server

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have a windows service that needs to get data from a web page.

```
try
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    byte[] test = client.DownloadData(url);

    Encoding latin1 = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
    string s = latin1.GetString(test);
    htmlDoc.LoadHtml(s);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    log.Fatal(ex.Message);
}
```

**This code works perfectly fine when I'm debugging**, I then install the service on my external webserver (using installutil) but when I try to launch the service it crashes on this particular line.

For some reason the error is not getting logged, so I don't understand why my code is failing. I'm guessing the service shuts down before getting into the catch.

I have also tried using HtmlAgilityPack's HtmlWeb.Load(url) but it crashed the same (which is logical I guess^^).

I've tried adding firewall security rules on the server (authorize inbound and outbound traffic on port 80) with no success.

I'm all out of ideas, any help would be greatly appreciated :)

PS: I know very little about windows services, it's the first one I have ever made.

Comment: Replace everything in the try with `throw null;` to make sure that your error handling is at fault. After that experiment you know that this has nothing to do with web stuff.

Comment: Thanks for your response, with throw null the error is logged correctly. I have no idea why the web stuff is not getting caught..

Comment: That is curious. Simplify the web stuff until the error "is logged correctly". Then examine the last change you made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out what the problem was.

The IP of my webserver must be banned from the site I'm trying to access.
I tried accessing the url using IE on my server, and the page just timed out..
My service was unable to start simply because it was taking too much time to launch due to the timed out page. It was not actually crashing, hence no exception was getting caught.

Silly me, should have tried this before. Hope this can help someone.

Cheers